# sass Undefined mixin

Tags: sass, vuejs3, vite

I follow a vedio(https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1dS4y1y7vd?p=15&vd_source=038a48dbf1db30c14d9dfe23dcf7da9e) to fulfill the task about BEM.However,some mistakes generate.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mugjv.png)

src/App.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="xm-test">
    小满
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang='ts'>
import {ref,reactive,onMounted} from 'vue'
</script>
<style lang='scss'>

@include b(test){
  color:red;
}
</style>
```

src/bem.scss

```
$block-sel: "-" !default;
$element-sel: "__" !default;
$modifier-sel: "--" !default;
$namespace:'xm' !default;
 
//混入
@mixin b($block) {
   $B: $namespace + $block-sel + $block; //变量
   .#{$B}{ //插值语法#{}
     @content; //内容替换
   }
}
 
@mixin e($element) {
    $selector:&;
    @at-root {
        #{$selector + $element-sel + $element} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
 
@mixin m($modifier) {
    $selector:&;
    @at-root {
        #{$selector + $modifier-sel + $modifier} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  css:{
    preprocessorOptions:{
      scss:{
        additionalData:`@import "./src/bem.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I have spent one hour to find what wrong with it,but can do nothing.Can anyone help me?Send my best gratitute to you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't just include it like you did. The include tag needs to be in a selector block. Your mixin name is not `b(test){ color:red; }` but `b(test)`

This is wrong:

```html
<style lang='scss'>

@include b(test){
  color:red;
}
</style>
```

This is correct :

```html
<style lang='scss'>

.some-selector{
    @include b(some-value);
}
</style>
```